# Is it possible to protect from downloading an audio from a site

Tags: laravel, audio, html5-audio

I want to create an audio-book application using Laravel.

Is it possible to protect from `downloading an audio` from a site ?

Is `right click disable` does the trick ***OR***

What security measures will I take to **prevent any audio files download ?**

Meanwhile I have decided to use `HTML5-Audio Player`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is complicated, and depending on how you deliver the audio, the answer will changes. I would recommend to look at how protected content are delivered on certain platform.

Let take a look at Spotify, they are using `Widevine`:

> Widevine is a proprietary digital rights management (DRM) technology from Google used by the Google Chrome, Brave and Firefox web browsers (including some derivatives), Android MediaDRM, Android TV, and other consumer electronics devices.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widevine)

Simply disabling the download is only a frontend feature removed, that can be easily bypass. For protected content, more complicated solution are required like a DRM.